# Popcorn JS - YouTube - Memory usage

Tags: javascript, memory, youtube, youtube-api, popcornjs

If I set up a series of YouTube videos to play in sequence, using Popcorn JS's HTMLYouTubeVideoElement and changing the media.src, the memory usage of the page is very large. An example is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65dn6/1/).

```
var youtubeIds = ["qe3ZZMfzBnM", "WiGVSqRE7V0", "VBi7M5aFv5g", "0pfxsxe1M-I", "-zcLRW53h-w"];
var index = 0;
var playerPrefix = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/";
var media;
var player;

function nextVideo() {
    index++;
    if (index==youtubeIds.length) index=0;

    console.log("nextVideo", index);
    player.media.src = playerPrefix + youtubeIds[index];

    player.play();
}

media = Popcorn.HTMLYouTubeVideoElement("#video");
console.log(media);
player = Popcorn(media);
media.src = playerPrefix + youtubeIds[index];

player.cue(5, nextVideo);
player.play();
```

Opening this is Google Chrome and viewing the Task Manager, the memory usage of the page increases quickly. After only about 10 videos, the memory can reach 1GB. I understand videos are large objects and Chrome is doing a lot of caching / buffering for my benefit, but this seems excessive.

Should I be influencing the memory management in some way, e.g. destroying and re-building the player, or is this out of my control? Does it not matter because Chrome will use the memory it has available and clear it up when it needs too?

Comment: I try your code, it's all fine for me. Google Chrome like eat your memory, he is like that, but you definitely don't need to destroy your player. Destroying the player is only if you are sure that people don't see more videos.

Comment: Thanks @martialdidit. I am using Google Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 on Ubuntu 14.04. What did you try it with?

Comment: In several browsers with the Task Manager opened to see what happens. I notice nothing particular, maybe it's one of your plugin, check your code in secret mode of Google Chrome, you will see.